# How To Log Effectively Without Flooding Log Files

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection

In an application with long running task and dependency injection log files can easily become flooded with useless data. This makes it harder to follow log files and drains storage space.

Examples:

1. **A background service that polls** a database every 10 seconds for data and logs to say that it is checking for data and how much data is retrieved
2. A **transient service (DI)** that has some logging in a method called by the constructor

For example 1, the background service logging is useful for diagnostics when something goes wrong but can easily flood the log file.

For example 2, each time the transient service is constructed, (which might be a lot) that logging in the method called by the constructor is logged.

Obviously, the logs can be split into different files e.g. debug level log file and general log file - this can make the general log file easier to follow but doesn't deal with log files taking up too much space. It also may result in the separation some info that paints a clearer picture of what is happening.

Is there anything more that can be done apart from splitting up the log files and being more selective about what's logged. Are there any best practices for this or any resources that provide good approaches to tackling this problem, or is it just a case of figuring out what's best to do in the specific scenario at hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to control the logging behaviour by using the correct LogLevel when logging messages.
You should have a look at the [LogLevel Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loglevel?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) as it will clearly show you when to use which level.
In the appsettings.json of your application you can then set the minimum log level depending on the deployment environment.

You are referring to trace or information logging which should only be used in a test or development environment in order to get as much information as possible when something is wrong.
Usually only enabled when you are trying to reproduce a known error.

In a production environment you will only log Error or Critical messages. In your exception handling you could log some additional information about parameters that where passed into the failing method along with the stack trace. This should give you enough information to reproduce the error in dev or test where you can debug the application or enable trace logs.

Consider using [Structured Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/logging-tracing#structured-logging) for those scenarios.